# Useragent not working on newly updated web browsers

Tags: javascript

window.orientation is still working for mobiles but somehow it stop working

```
var brow = navigator.userAgent;
if (/mobi/i.test(brow)) {
```

not working anymore

especially in opera, any old alternatives ?

Comment: What newly updated browsers are you talking about, what user agent strings do they use specifically?

Comment: maybe its just not matching, `navigator.userAgent` has not been removed, rtm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instead

```
    var orientation = 
screen.orientation    ||
screen.mozOrientation ||
screen.msOrientation  ||

null; if (orientation === null) {
   // API not supported
} else if (typeof orientation === 'object') {
   // new versions supported
} else {
   // old versions supported
}
```

Copied